# MySQL: What points should we consider when create composite index

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

There are multiple views behind the logic of creating composite index in a table. Creating composite index is obvious when we have composite primary key. 
Beside this, we create composite index on the basis of our SQL query requirements. Ordering of column in a composite index plays a vital role in the selection of right index in query execution which improves the performance.
If a composite index has only 2 columns then its easy to determine their order.

- But, how we will decide the ordering of columns if we have many
  columns and many different SQL queries.
- What are the other points which should be focused when create composite index?
- What is the role of cardinality and modality of a column in creating index and composite indices?

Answer (score 1):

> But, how we will decide the ordering of columns if we have many columns and many different SQL queries.

More selective columns should go first.

> What are the other points which should be focused when create composite index?

Not necessary all fields on an index may be used. For example, if you have index `(a, b, c)` and `WHERE` clause looks like

```
WHERE a = 5 and b < 10 and c = 6
```

then only a and b fields may be used. A field with `<` or `>` will be the last one that's used.

> What is the role of cardinality and modality of a column in creating index and composite indices?

Cardinality of a set is number of element in the set. The higher cardinality of a field values set the closer the fields should come in the composite index.

Comment: Given the WHERE clause in your answer,, the index should really be `(a,c,b)`. That should yield a smaller index scan.